# Object of abstract class type "Animal" is not allowed: (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to store things into vector but there're few problems.
These are my code.

**Animal.cpp**

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cattle.h"
#include "Sheep.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Animal::Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newaccDose, char newsex)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    yy = yy;
    mm = mm;
    dd = dd;
    dose = newaccDose;
    sex = newsex;
}

Animal::Animal()
{
    id = 0;
    weight = 0;
    yy = 0;
    mm = 0;
    dd = 0;
    dose = 0;
    sex = ' ';
}

Animal::~Animal(){}

double Animal::getDaysDifference(){
    jdate dateOfBirth(dd,mm,yy);
    jdate now;
    double diff = now-dateOfBirth;
    return diff;
}

void Animal::addAnimal(){
    int select=0;
    int id;

    cout << "1.  Cattle    2.  Sheep" << endl;
    cout << "Select a type of animal: ";
    cin >> select;

    if(select==1){
        Cattle* c1;
        cout << "Please answer following questions" << endl;
        cout << "Type the animal's ID: ";
        cin >> id;

        c1->setID(id);

        //vector<Animal> vec;
        //vector<Animal>::iterator vec_ite;

    }else if(select==2){
        Sheep* s1;
        cout << "Please answer following questions" << endl;
        cout << "Type the animal's ID: ";
        cin >> id;

        s1->setID(id);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid number please try again" << endl;  
    }
}
```

First off, in the code above, `Cattle* c1` and `Sheep* s1`, it doesn't have an error.
and even if I code like `s1->setID(id)` it's fine. However,

**Cattle.cpp**

```
#include "Cattle.h"

Cattle::Cattle(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, 
           double newdose, char newsex, string newcategory)
    : Animal(id, weight, yy,mm,dd, dose, sex)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    dose = newdose;
    sex = newsex;
    Cattle::category = newcategory;
}

Cattle::Cattle(){
    id = 0;
    weight = 0;
    dose = 0;
    sex = ' ';
    Cattle::category = "";
}

Cattle::~Cattle(){}

string Cattle::getCategory(){
    return category;
}

double Cattle::calcDose(){
    Cattle* c1;
    if(c1->getDaysDifference() < 90 || c1->getCategory() == "Meat"){
        c1->dose = 0;
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else if(c1->getCategory() == "Dairy"){
        if (c1->weight < 250 || c1->dose > 200){
            c1->dose = 0;
        }
        else{
            c1->dose = c1->weight * 0.013 + 46;
        }
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else if(c1->getCategory() == "Breeding"){
        if (c1->weight < 250 || c1->dose > 250){
            c1->dose = 0;
        }
        else{
            c1->dose = c1->weight * 0.021 + 81;
        }
        return c1->dose;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It is not valid category" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Animal.h**

```
#ifndef ANI_H
#define ANI_H
#include <vector>
#include "Treatment.h"
#include "jdate.h"

class Animal{
protected:
    int id;
    double weight;
    int yy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
    double dose;
    char sex;
    //Treatment treatArray[];
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newdose, char newsex);
    ~Animal();

    virtual double calcDose() = 0;
    void addAnimal();
    double getDaysDifference();
};
#endif
```

**DrugAdmin.cpp (main)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cattle.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Animal* a1=new Animal;
    delete a1;

    a1->addAnimal();
}
```

The problem is here, when I try to define `Animal* a1=new Animal;
        delete a1;` it says `Object of abstract class type "Animal" is not allowed:`
I've Googled and Binged here and there, and I figured out I cannot define the abstract base class itself but subclasses.
So I tried the same thing in `Cattle.cpp` using `Cattle c1=new Cattle;` but it doesn't work either..

I'm really not sure what's wrong with that..
Could you help me please?

Cheers

Comment: For one thing, you are missing the distinction between pointers and objects.

Comment: Upon closer look at your code, you have plenty of dangerous codes in Animal and Cattle, like using a local pointer Cattle* c1 inside Cattle::calcDose() without ever initialising it. Please go back and read up on pointers, learn how to use them properly and fix your code before you continue and wreck this program beyond recognition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`virtual double calcDose()`

This says "It is possible to `calcDose()` for everything which is an Animal, and different Animals may do it differently..."

`= 0;`

"... but there is no 'generic' way to do it for Animals; each one must specify its own method".

You may not construct an unspecified sort of Animal because, by definition, a key piece of information is missing: how to `calcDose` for it.

This is all well and good. Chances are, you don't really want to construct an unspecified Animal, for the same reason that in real life, you wouldn't go to a farm (Zoo? Pet store?) to buy "an animal" without having any specific preconception of what kind of Animal you want.

The type `Animal` exists so that you can omit the information about what kind of Animal something is **when it is appropriate to do so**. Creating the instance is not one of those times, in your case.

---

Also, `addAnimal` makes absolutely **no** sense as a member function of `Animal`, no matter how much you might think it does. There are three fundamental problems:

1) since it's a non-static member function, you already require an `Animal` to call the function. That's kind of a catch-22.

2) You don't have anywhere to add the animal **to**. You need some kind of container.

3) Conceptually, making a list of Animals is **not the animals' responsibility**. It's the responsibility of whoever needs the list.

4) In general, it is good policy to have clean separation between the code that asks the user for information, and the code which acts upon that information. Write a **free** (meaning, not part of a class) function that asks for the information, constructs the Animal and **returns** that pointer; then in the calling code, store the pointer in a container.

Except you *don't really want to use raw pointers for this anyway*. You should be using some kind of smart pointer, or else putting the pointers into one of the boost `ptr_container` s.

Comment: Thanks very much, I probably considered c++ too easily,
I should study more! Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 3):

`Animal` is an abstract class, which means it has *pure* virtual function(s). This is the pure virtual function in `Animal`.

```
virtual double calcDose() = 0;
```

Object of an abstract class cannot be created. It is true not only in C++, rather in all object oriented languages whichever support  *pure* virtual function (some languages, such as C#, calls it `abstract` method.)

If you remove the pure specifier which is `=0` part in the declaration, as marked below:

```
virtual double calcDose() = 0;
                       //^^^^ this is called pure specifier
```

then it will become *virtual* function (as opposed to *pure* virtual function). Now, you've to define the *virtual* function, and you can create objects of `Animal` then, as it is no more an *abstract* class.

Answer (score 1):

In `Animal`, you have:

```
virtual double calcDose() = 0;
```

So that class is abstract and cannot be instantiated. You can only construct objects of classes that derive from it *and* implement that method.

Comment: If I remove virtual, would there be any problem with inheritance?

Comment: yes that would work, or you can remove the "= 0" and give a default definition, and then it would work

Comment: Thanks very much!
but, what's difference between Cattle* c1, and Animal* a1 = new Animal;

As you can see I could create the former one but the latter.

Comment: @jcarlos: you cannot create an object from an abstract class. Animal is abstract as long as it has an `=0` method. Cattle isn't abstract since it implements the abstract methods from its parent, so you can create objects from that class.